Copy/paste values without changing active workbook/sheet
I can copy cells by activating the worksheet first.
Shouldn't I be able to copy without activating the worksheet?
Sub test()
    Dim wbSource, wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
    
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(1)
    
    'Doesnt work
    wsSource.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Copy
    
    'Works
    'wsSource.Activate
    'Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Copy
    
    wsTarget.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
End Sub

I get:

"Run-time error '1004':"
"Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed"

Swapping out the part which doesn't work with the code which does (commented out) results in:

Excel flickering through every sheet (if the data was spread out on several sheets in wbSource)
If a user performs an input which changes the active sheet, the macro can break (copy/paste the wrong values).

Swapping out
wsSource.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Copy

with
wsSource.Range("A1:B2").Copy

works, but I need to change the rows and columns dynamically.
I am trying to not alternate between active workbooks, so I am not dependent on which workbook/worksheet is currently active (selected window).
Ultimately I'm trying to avoid; a user clicks on anything that changes the active workbook/worksheet while a macro is running and messes up the sequence.


wsTarget.Range("A1:B2").Value = wsSource.Range("A1:B2").Value


When Range is defined through the Cells object they also must be qualified like in the edited code
Sub test()
    Dim wbSource, wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
    
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(1)
    
    'Doesnt work     'edited
    wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(1, 1), wsSource.Cells(2, 2)).Copy
    
    'Works
    'wsSource.Activate
    'Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Copy
    
    
    wsTarget.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
End Sub


Thanks :) . I knew I was missing something syntax-wise.  I did search around but could figure out what I was missing

You wouldn't happen to also have an answer for my 3.rd question?

What you did is a reason to close called Needs more focus. Pls. have a look SO. You edited your question and insert another question in it. This needs a new post with the new problem, where you have to post the code you tried, the received error and additional information to reproduce the issue.
